# How to convert MP3 file MPEG-2 Layer 3 version to MPEG-1 Layer 3 version?

Tags: mp3, audio-conversion, mpeg

I have searched for this all over but couldn't find an answer other than people saying "there is virtually no difference between MPEG version 1 and 2". But the thing is, some old players do NOT support MPEG Version 2, like some cars' multimedia systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many converters that I could find. None of the available converters offer a version selection while converting to MP3. I could find only one person mentioning this on the internet here: [Converting MPEG-2 Layer 3 to MPEG-1 Layer 3 audio](https://superuser.com/questions/644245/converting-mpeg-2-layer-3-to-mpeg-1-layer-3-audio)

That the Lame encoder chooses the version automatically and that you can't force change it. I am writing this answer to clarify this a little. If your file is MPEG Version 2, probably your file's sampling rate is 22kHz. (22050 MHz to be precise.) With any converter, change the sampling to 44.1kHz and save again, your MPEG version will automatically convert from Version 2 to Version 1, since Version 2 doesn't support sampling over 24kHz.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).